# VMWARE import packer job stuck at "Starting rename of AMI"

Tags: amazon-ami, packer, ova, aws-vm-import

trying to build AMI with the OVA import to S3. it was working all the while but now I could see the jobs are stuck at  "Starting rename of AMI" In reality the import job succeeds. Please help.

```
aws@Cloud-Automation-Host:~$ aws  ec2 describe-import-image-tasks -- 
import-task-ids import-ami-067ff7c968962fffb
{
    "ImportImageTasks": [
        {
            "Status": "completed",
           "LicenseType": "BYOL",
            "ImageId": "ami-0778e29c4926231de",
            "Platform": "Linux",
            "Architecture": "x86_64",
            "SnapshotDetails": [
                {
                    "Status": "completed",
                    "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
                    "Format": "VMDK",
                    "DiskImageSize": 2152929792.0,
                    "SnapshotId": "snap-0a9e836f4359eeca2",
                    "UserBucket": {
                        "S3Bucket": "***-jenkins-us-west-1",
                        "S3Key": "**-6cce79e-***.ova"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "ImportTaskId": "import-ami-067ff7c968962fffb"
        }
    ]
}



[packer-host] out: 2019/02/20 06:54:50 packer: 2019/02/20 06:54:50 Allowing 
300s to complete (change with AWS_TIMEOUT_SECONDS)
[packer-host] out: 2019/02/20 07:10:33 ui: [0;32m    vmware-iso (amazon- 
import): Import task import-ami-085c7a13345948192 complete[0m
[packer-host] out: [0;32m    vmware-iso (amazon-import): Import task import- 
ami-085c7a13345948192 complete[0m
[packer-host] out: 2019/02/20 07:10:33 ui: [0;32m    vmware-iso (amazon- 
import): Starting rename of AMI (ami-0c843c10c8c2f641c)[0m
[packer-host] out: [0;32m    vmware-iso (amazon-import): Starting rename of 
AMI (ami-0c843c10c8c2f641c)[0m
```

Comment: [aws@kvm1: ~]# packer -v
    1.1.2

Comment: Can somebody help on this please?